# Structure Statistics Data for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-design, mongoose, mongoid, database

We have videos who got a certain amount of views every day.

I was thinking doing:

```
{
    video_name: "Blabla"
    stats: [
      {day: x, views: 342}
      {day: x, views: 342}
     ]
}
```

However, from what I've read online for analytics/data stuff, people tend to prefer a separated collection, so more something like this:

```
{
    video_name: "Blabla"
}

{day: x, views: 342, video_id: y}
{day: x, views: 342, video_id: y}
```

What's your views?

Comment: What do your users need, and how will your queries be constructed? The challenge of putting the stats in a single document/video might mean that you'll hit the 16MB MongoDB document limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this task is classical for aggregation framework: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/
for first variant you may used something like this:

```
test> db.video.aggregate([{$unwind:'$stats'}, {$group:{_id:{name:'$video_name', day:'$stats.day'}, views:{$sum:'$stats.views'}}}])
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "name" : "Blabla2",
                "day" : 3
            },
            "views" : 344
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "name" : "Blabla2",
                "day" : 1
            },
            "views" : 684
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "name" : "Blabla",
                "day" : 2
            },
            "views" : 342
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "name" : "Blabla2",
                "day" : 2
            },
            "views" : 342
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "name" : "Blabla",
                "day" : 1
            },
            "views" : 342
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
```

but you may had problems in the future if your count of video will be increased like avalanche.
you may calculate statistics exactly for certain day with the help $match operation, but this is temporary solution.

**Good idea is a change data model** to more simple (if you can):

```
{
    video_name: "Blabla",
    day: x,
    views: 342}
}
```

in this model, you do not depend on the size of the document and aggregation framework help your creating analitical views:

```
db.video.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{name:'$video_name', day:'$day'}, views:{$sum:'$views'}}}])
```

you may simple select any of day or day intervals, you may group by name of video or video and day, you may free calculate any statistics as you wish ;)

Comment: and another good idea: save some aggegation statistics in different collection and periodically update this for analitical purpose

you must separate oltp and analitics

Comment: If I get his correctly the correct way of doing stuff, is to have a separated collections and use the aggregation framework to do stuff?

Comment: yes, imho it's a best way. If you mixed the statistics and data you will always have difficulty with update, just imagine, how you will update the number of views and what code it would be required

Comment: make senses. I guess what make me confused in the MongoDB seemed to emphase on making data embedded when it can be a document.